# Array of Random Birthdays

Tags: java, arrays

After processing all of the N people, iterate over your array to compute:
For each month, the fraction (or percentage) of people born in that month.
The average of the 12 values you computed for the above.
For each day, the fraction (or percentage) of people born on that day, whether in the same or in a different month.
The average of the 31 values you computed for the above.
The fraction (or percentage) of people born on exactly the same day.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArgsProcessor ap = new ArgsProcessor(args);
    int N = ap.nextInt("Number of people?");
    int [][] birthday = new int[12][31];


    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        int month = (int)(Math.random()*12);
        int day = (int)(Math.random()*31); 
        birthday[month][day] = birthday[month][day] + 1;  
    }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: It would appear that you need an array of Dates

Comment: @ScaryWombat As I understand the question is the the number of people born on a. each month (1-12) which can be represented by int[12]  b. on each day of a month (1-31) which can be represented by int[31]

Comment: What id your question ?